# Can I fix the paint brush bug in Elder Scrolls: Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I was completing the Miscarcand quest, and had collected a lot of loot. I decided to drop the things I don't really need, but when I drop paint brushes, they just float in the air.

I tried pressing the hold button, but that does not work. The paint brushes all do the same thing. I want them to use physics. Is there any way to stop this floating paint brush bug? Are there any cheats for turning the physics back on?

Comment: There would not be cheats to turn the physics on, as this was not an intended behaviour. [This is a well known bug across PC and console](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Paint_Brush#Bugs).

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to fix the ["floating paintbrush bug"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Exploitable_Glitches#Floating_Paint_Brushes). [It is a bug that is well known](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Paint_Brush#Bugs), and the focus of many other [in-game exploits](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion_talk:Glitches#Get_to_the_end_of_the_game_with_only_paintbrushes). There has not been an official patch to fix the bug, and it was not an intended mechanic, so naturally the developers have not included any cheat to "turn the physics back on".

### The Bug:

Basically, all paint brushes you drop have a high chance of hovering in the air. These brushes still detect collision, and can even be used as makeshift platforms. In some cases, I have seen this mechanic used as a **fix** for other, less desirable bugs and behaviors.

### Bug Fixes:

**The bug has been fixed with the [Unofficial Oblivion Patch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Tes4Mod:Unofficial_Oblivion_Patch)**, which can be applied to the computer platform. Alternatively, if you are playing on console, this bug is reported to be fixed in the PlayStation 3 version of the Game of the Year edition. There is no reported fix on Xbox 360.

### Ignoring the Problem:

An alternate way to "fix the problem" is to simply not pick up paintbrushes. Oblivion uses an item weight and capacity mechanic, to prevent your character from moving or fast-travelling when they become 'over-encumbered'. As such, it is counter productive to pick up 'junk'. As paintbrushes do not carry a high value, and serve more to weigh the player down; it would be a good strategy to simply not pick them up, to begin with. From what I understand, this bug can sometimes effect other items, but favors junk.

The best strategy for a PC gamer not wishing to install unofficial modification, a PlayStation gamer stuck with an older copy, or a 360 gamer would be to simply not pick up 'junk items' to begin with. The bug will not effect your experience in any way, and your adventuring will be a tiny bit more efficient for not having to stop to drop loot as often.

Comment: I'm on Xbox 360, so no luck for me.

Comment: @Jim, I'm surprised the bug is that noticeable, to be honest. I spent over 100 hours on computer, and 100% completed it on Xbox 360. I did not even realise this was a thing, until I looked it up for this answer.